# Navigate Sylius theme templates in PhpStorm

Tags: symfony, twig, themes, phpstorm, sylius

When I'm building my own Sylius theme
And I click on the template name with the CMD button pressed
Then I expect to be able to navigate to that template inside my theme: `themes/ThemeName/templates/bundles/SyliusShopBundle/Layout/Header/_logo.html.twig`
But it is not present in popup choices:

[image: Not all places present]

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a file

`themes/ThemeName/ide-twig.json`

with next content:

```
{
  "namespaces": [
    {
      "path": "templates/bundles/SyliusAdminBundle",
      "namespace": "SyliusAdmin"
    },
    {
      "path": "templates/bundles/SyliusShopBundle",
      "namespace": "SyliusShop"
    },
    {
      "path": "templates/bundles/SyliusUiBundle",
      "namespace": "SyliusUi"
    }
  ]
}
```

After that - expected choices are shown and I can navigate with two clicks:

[image: Correct choices]

If something doesn't work - probably your JSON file has typos (for example, the last items shouldn't end with a comma).

Inspired by https://tomasvotruba.com/blog/2019/01/28/2-files-that-your-symfony-application-misses/